Python 3.12. No se abre la imagen con PIllow y muestra error
Queria mostrar una imagen con las librerias tkinter y Pillow pero sale error, la imagen que queria subir esta en la misma carpeta.
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

ventana = tk.Tk()
imagen = Image.open("imagen.jpg")
imagen_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
etiqueta = tk.Label(ventana, image=imagen_tk)
etiqueta.pack()

ventana.mainloop()

Ya coloque el nombre de la imagen en Image.open() pero no funciona, el error especificamente es:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Python\tkinter\Imagenes.py", line 5, in <module>
    imagen = Image.open("imagen.jpg")
 File"C:\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_q5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3431, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

La verdad soy programador Junior así que aunque se ingles no entiendo muy bien los errores, ayuda porfa

Hola Andy  ¿Cuál es el error exactamente? Agrega a la pregunta la traza completa  (no solo el error), como texto por favor,. Sin eso poco podemos ayudar, el código en si es correcto ,por lo que no podemos siquiera replicar el error.  Si es un FileNotFoundError ten en cuenta que lo importante no es dónde está la imagen con respecto al script, sino cual es el CWD en el momento en el que se intenta abrir.

Andy a la traza de la excepción que has agregado le falta justamente la última línea, que es la que nos dice error concreto. Si es un FileNotFoundError, comenta el código que tienes y agrega esta línea al script import pathlib;print(f"FILE: {__file__}\nCWD: {pathlib.Path.cwd()}\nLISTDIR: {list(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.iterdir())}") y muestra que te imprime, esto debe mostrar la ruta del script, el CWD y los archivos/directorios de la carpeta que contiene al script.
